# Magnet App will not work with some applications

Tags: applications, window-manager, monterey

I just downloaded the Magnet app. I have Chrome and the mail app open. When I drag chrome to the side, it snaps to half the screen size, as it should. But, when I try the Mail app, it snaps to slighty over half the screen width and displays the message "Can't be more narrow". This also happened for Spotify. I am running macOS Monterey. Why is it doing this?

Comment: I have a similar problem... but not going half the screen size, my problem is trying to snap a Chrome or Firefox window to FULL size and I get that error message.  

Of course, I can manually drag the window to the full size by hand if I want, but Magnet won't do it.  Safari works and most apps seem fine... but Chrome and Firefox for sure have issues.

I suppose this isn't an "answer", but more of a 'me too' problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to one of [the Q&A's](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/faq.html) on Magnet's web site:

> Some apps don’t resize to a half screen and remain wider. What’s wrong?
>
> Certain apps require a minimal width of their window. In some cases the width can exceed half of your screen, particularly on small screens like Macbooks'.

Answer (score 3):

Found a Reddit thread that talked about this and someone proposed a better option called Rectangle: https://rectangleapp.com/

Works pretty awesome -- AND with Chrome!  I just uninstalled Magnet and started using Rectangle.

Here's the original post: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/rx2zfn/bettersnaptool_and_magnet_not_working_for_google/

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly like magnet, and it's free + open source.  Window sizing is working again +1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but then I used the keyboard shortcuts and it worked.

You can find the short in the drop-down menu.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems like this answer may be a more suitable comment.